# JPA EntityManager why merge() does not make the instance managed?

Tags: jpa, openjpa, entitymanager

When I call merge() on an object, the object does not become managed. Instead a reference to a managed instance of the same entity is returned. What is the logic behind this? Is there a way to change this behavior (and make the object managed) through some settings? I am using OpenJPA 2.2. Thank you.

Comment: You mean the L1 cache of the EntityManager already has a managed object with an identity, and you merge some detached object with that same identity and it returns the already managed one ? or do you mean that there wasn't already an instance in the L1 cache with that identity when the merge happened so it created the new managed object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that merge() is not attaching object to EntityManager context, it is returning attached objects. So, if we have:

```
AEntity a2 = entityManager.merge(a1);
```

a1 remains not managed, while a2 is managed.

This is, by the way, clever approach since merge does not cause side effects, passed object state is not changed.

Comment: Thank you, Piotr. I guess the idea here is to avoid side effects. I was concerned that I was not using it correctly.